# Mongodb query which avoid duplicates items with different _id

Tags: mongodb

I'm working with dump of events provided by 3rd party side. And in this dump they have duplicates events, which is fully identical, but have different _id. So my goal is to provide unique only data, so I can't use duplicates event.
Is it possible to build the query which return me only documents with unique value?

Lets say, in each document i have `EventId` field, and I need all the events, with unique `EventID`

I can't change dump, have only read permission to it.

Comment: Your comment on one of the answers implies you want to compare all fields? Is that true, or is just a single field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use db.collection.distinct() method http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: distinct return only unique fields, but not whole documents. So that's not what I need.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Then, I cannot think of other option than filtering in the application... Let's hope anyone else has a better suggestion than this one.